# User session does not get destroyed Nodejs

Tags: node.js, reactjs

Guys I have this logout button on my react app that executes the LogoutSession() function that goes like this:

```
<span onClick={LogoutSession} className="btn btn-light rounded-pill text-primary py-2 
px-4 ms-lg-5">Log Out</span>
```

And this is the function:

```
const LogoutSession = (e) =>{
    e.preventDefault();
    Axios.get('http://localhost:3001/logout')
}
```

And in my server side (nodejs) I have this route:

```
router.get('/logout', async(req,res) => {
    req.session.destroy();
    console.log(req.session)
});
```

And I guess the problem is with the LogoutSession function cause I didn't know how to use Axios well to make that route work, is there any parameters that I'm missing or something I did wrong in the client side

Comment: At least make sure you properly end the request by using `res.end()` in the `GET /logout` handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the session to null will also work:

```
req.session = null;
```